# is it possible to set javascript:void(0) with #map for tabs in href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

i want to set JavaScript:void(0) with #map tabs in h ref. i want to set JavaScript:void(0) which is responsible for not to load the webpage on click. #map is tab .so i want to set both JavaScript:void(0) and #map. 
my code is

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#map" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getvalue('+val['product_id']+');" id="maptab">map</a></li>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap. If so, you don't need to do that; Bootstrap prevents the default action of the tab's `a` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use both actually you can use `.preventDefault()` when you write javascript function for this `<a>`.

```
$('li a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //... other code of function
})
```

> `.preventDefault()` prevents the default function of the element. so the page load will be prevented with this.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest change to your code is to remove that second `href` (you can't have two copies of the same attribute) and just add `return false;` to your existing `onclick`:

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#map" onclick="getvalue('+val['product_id']+');return false;" id="maptab">map</a></li>
<!-- Note --------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --->
```

`return false;` in an `onxyz` attribute handler prevents the default action, which is following the link; more in my blog post [*The true store on `return false`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html).

---

That said, I suggest avoiding `onxyz` attribute handlers in favor of `data-*` attributes (where needed) and delegated event handling.